# Can't open Anaconda Prompt(anaconda3) due to white spaces in user name

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tensorflow, keras, anaconda

Recently, I upgraded to Windows 2004 and since then getting the following message on opening Anaconda Prompt.

> [image]

Tried editing the activate.bat file with

> @SET
> TMP=C:\CondaTmp
> @SET TEMP=C:\CondaTmp

Also created a folder C:\CondaTmp.

But then got.

> "failed to create process."

on opening anaconda prompt.

How to run anaconda prompt successfully, now?

Thank you.

Comment: @TERMINATOR tried that but the same result. ??

Answer (score 1):

This is still a problem without a patch resulting from the `Windows 8.3` filename convention Where `Windows` creates a short name of each `path` after being created, and this short name often has a space which anaconda refusses to pick up. Before you can do any of this you must reinstall anaconda since the setup has already done some of the setup before failing.

Luckily, there are workarounds.

### Here are your option currently:

You can assign a short name without spaces yourself  using the following command:

`fsutil file setshortname "c:\program files" PROGRA~1`

**OR:**

You can disable the `Windows 8.3`  naming convention ny using this command:

```
fsutil 8dot3name set 1
```

**OR:**

Edit `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat` to add the following just before the first `@if`:

```
@set TEMP=C:/temp
@set TMP=C:/temp
```

**OR:**

Some users find that by opening `Anaconda` in `PowerShell` Anaconda does not have issues with whitespace

**OR:**

You can create an acount with no whitespaces untill this glitch is patched(ie `TERMINATOR ROCKS`-`Terminator_rocks`)

Comment: sorry, but none of them helped. Even changing the user name didn't help. The username was still showing with whitespaces.

Comment: I edited my answer to suggest a complete reinstall as this could be the isue